# ACF repeater - apply different row last repeater

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, advanced-custom-fields

I use ACF repeater in my wordpress website.

Each repeater display in a `col-md-6`.
I would like to display the last in a `col-md-12`.

```
<div class="container">
            <?php if ( have_rows( 'salon' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="row">
                <?php while ( have_rows( 'salon' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h2 class="card-title">Card title</h2>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example with your code it's working for me.

```
<?php if( have_rows('services_repeater', $services) ): ?>
    <?php $rowCount = count( get_field('services_repeater', $services) ); //GET THE COUNT ?>
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('services_repeater', $services) ): the_row(); ?>

        <?php // vars
            $service = get_sub_field('service');
            $description = get_sub_field('description');
        ?>

        <span class="hint--bottom" data-hint="<?php echo $description; ?>"><?php echo $service; ?></span>
        <?php if($i < $rowCount): ?>
            <div id="separator"> / </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is get the number of `salon` fields via `count()` and then check whether that number equals the row index. When it does set the `col-md-12` text as the variable, otherwise fallback to `col-md-6` text. Use that variable as the class.

```html
<div class="container">
  <?php if ( have_rows( 'salon' ) ) :
    $salon_count = count(get_field( 'salon' ));
  ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'salon' ) ) : the_row();
      $row_index = get_row_index();
      $salon_col = ($row_index == $salon_count) ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-6';
    ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $salon_col; ?>">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title">Card title</h2>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```